# Tuya wifi switch with WR4 flashable or replaceable?

Tags: smart-home, tasmota

I recently got a wifi switches with the Tuya WR4 WiFi chip. I want to know:

1. Has anyone had success flashing with tasmota?
2. Can it be replaced with an esp01?